# Linq query for Sub/Group max twice

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Emp { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime AccessTime { get; set; }
}

var events = new List<Event>(){
    new Event(){Id=1,Emp ="A",EventDate= new DateTime(2017, 1, 2), AccessTime= DateTime.Now},
    new Event(){Id=2,Emp ="A",EventDate= new DateTime(2017, 1, 2), AccessTime= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(4)},
    new Event(){Id=3,Emp ="A",EventDate= new DateTime(2017, 1, 2), AccessTime= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)},
    new Event(){Id=4,Emp ="A",EventDate= new DateTime(2017, 1, 3), AccessTime= DateTime.Now},
    new Event(){Id=5,Emp ="A",EventDate= new DateTime(2017, 1, 3), AccessTime= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2)},
    new Event(){Id=6,Emp ="A",EventDate= new DateTime(2017, 1, 3), AccessTime= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3)},
    new Event(){Id=7,Emp ="B",EventDate= new DateTime(2017, 2, 2), AccessTime= DateTime.Now},
    new Event(){Id=8,Emp ="B",EventDate= new DateTime(2017, 2, 2), AccessTime= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)},
    new Event(){Id=9,Emp ="B",EventDate= new DateTime(2017, 2, 2), AccessTime= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2)}
};
```

How to get Emps with latest EventDate and AccessTime? First, get the items with the lastest EventDate. If the EventDates are same, then get the item with the latest AccessTime. For this list, the result should be event 6 and 9.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why are you saying group by, it sounds like you just want a simple orderby right? `events.OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDate).ThenByDescending(x => x.AccessTime)` ?

Comment: Why does 2 is not in the result?

Comment: Sorry, my question should be more clear. It is grouped by Emp, Emp should appear only once in the result. The result should look like this : 

6 A 1/3/2017 12:00:00 AM 5/15/2017 3:48:57 PM 
9 B 2/2/2017 12:00:00 AM 5/15/2017 3:47:57 PM

Comment: @david I have updated my answer so that the result is what you need

Comment: That's the answer. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you what you want:

```
var result = events.GroupBy(x => x.Emp).Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(z => z.EventDate).ThenByDescending(q => q.AccessTime).First());
foreach (Event a in result)
{
            Console.WriteLine(a.Id + "\t" + a.Emp + "\t" + a.EventDate + "\t" + a.AccessTime);
}
```

First you need to `GroupBy` by Emp, than order groups first `OrderByDescending` by `EventDate`, than by `AccessTime` and  Select First Lines.

And the final result will be :

> 9
>   6

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`. In case of your example:

```
events.OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDate)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.AccessTime);
```

This will order your `events` by latest `EventDate` first and then by `AccessTime` (in case multiple dates match).

The result will have ID 9 followed by 8 since they have the latest `EventDate` and out of the two ID 9 has the latest `AccessTime`.

[Dotnet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dxGur7)